# Unable to plot aggregate vector using two factor variables - double bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have used the below code to successfully plot a similar vector ("todmc_v1"), but not working for the specific vector I'm having trouble with, which I will provide the `dput()` of.

```
ggplot(todmc_v1, aes(x=factor(tod, level = c('Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening', 'Late')), y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

Here is the `dput()` of the vector "rldow" that I am unable to plot:

```
structure(list(`data_2021_v2$member_casual` = c("casual", "member", 
"casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", 
"member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member"), `data_2021_v2$day_of_week` = c("Friday", 
"Friday", "Monday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Sunday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday"), `data_2021_v2$ride_length` = c(1760.09364802057, 
799.435593679782, 1891.04649254227, 794.827114155888, 2042.12860343406, 
915.879808325155, 2203.20327031892, 939.474596054804, 1623.62034644899, 
766.524376333107, 1665.79837660326, 767.099664854878, 1613.5331421196, 
768.874141204975)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Not sure if relevant, but this vector was created from an `aggregate` function, which is below:

```
rldow <- aggregate(data_2021_v2$ride_length ~ data_2021_v2$member_casual + data_2021_v2$day_of_week, FUN = mean)
```

I have tried to `melt()` the vector so it is sorted by column "member_casual" but variations I have tried end up with the column names in rows as values - which is very odd. This might also have something to do with why `dput()` included backticks around my column names. I know I could manually create the vector, but that would take time and am hoping I can use the `aggregate` function to create plottable vectors in the future.

So you have an idea of the output I'm looking for please see below screenshot - produced after I exported the data to EXCEL. I appreciate the help on this.

[image: Example of how I would like plot to appear]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I tried to reproduce your graph. The pattern of my `ggplot` graph and your Excel graphs are high similar, but I'm not sure what y-axis values are you using, the values range from 0 to 40 is not present in your `dput()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(factor(`data_2021_v2$day_of_week`, 
                      levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
                                 "Sunday")), 
               `data_2021_v2$ride_length`, 
               fill = fct_rev(`data_2021_v2$member_casual`))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("dodgerblue4", "darkorange2"), 
                    labels = c("Member Avg Ride Length", "Casual Avg Ride Length")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image: ggplot_mimic_excel]

Comment: This worked perfectly. To circle back, my code wasn't working because I had the column values within quotes instead of backticks. When I replaced, my original code worked. However, I tried seeing if the plot would work if I completely removed the backticks and it did not - returning `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (14): x, y and fill`. Any idea why the backticks are necessary here?  Other plots they are not.

Comment: Because your column names contain the special character `$`, which is normally used to extract a dataframe column (e.g. `df$A` extract column `A` from dataframe `df`). The backticks are there to ensure the string that it surround are read as a "sring". Therefore, if you omit it, `R` will look for column `day_of_week` from the dataframe `data_2021_v2`, which might not exist in your environment and thus, error as result.